# Angular2 restrict special characters in Template driven forms

Tags: angular

I want to restrict special characters in textbox.I mean if user enters any special characters they should not be displayed in the textbox.In Aangular 1  you can do that by using parsers. What is the best way to achieve that in Angular2.

**Update**
In an attempt to achieve desired result I have come up with this.

```
input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.name" #name="ngModel" #ctrlName     (onModelChange)="onChange('name')"

onChange(field : string){
    this.user["field"] = this.user["field"].replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '');
}
```

but this was not updating the control value so I modified it like below

```
input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.name" #name="ngModel" #ctrlName (onModelChange)="onChange('name',ctrlName)"

onChange(field : string,ctrl : FormControl){
    var value = this.user["field"].replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '');
    this.user["field"] = value;
    ctrl.value = value; 
}
```

but now when I enter a special character it is removed from the input but if i test it for required field validity like name.valid , it results true which means that it is not removed from the model.Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure that you can restrict data from appearing (well I know you ***can***), it may be easier to simply use Angular [reactive forms](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/reactive-forms.html) and custom validators

Comment: @Bwolfing But right now I'm using template-driven forms

Comment: @sqlcte Perhaps [this](https://juristr.com/blog/2016/11/ng2-template-driven-form-validators/) will help? Looks like you can do custom validation with template-driven, just takes a little extra work

Comment: @Bwolfing It looks good but I want to restrict user from entering special characters.I  dont want special characters to be displayed.What I want is to remove special character  whenever a user enters it  and update the model accordingly.

Comment: Someone please help.If I'm not clear enough you can ask me to make it more elaborate.

Comment: Could you do a check for disallowed characters in the `onChange()` event and then sanitize the string?